# Use of BSD-3 Clause license and python software license for proprietary use

Tags: commercial, bsd, proprietary-code, closed-source, python

I am making a software in python programming language which uses libraries licensed under BSD-3 clause. Is it necessary for me to show my source code to users? Also can I restrict the distribution of the binaries that I provide to the user like other proprietary software (Ex:Windows office package)?!

Comment: What do you mean by "python software license" in the title?

Comment: @MansGunnarsson : Python also has its own license (Python Software Foundation License).. I was wondering like GPL it also mandates the author to release source code to its users.. Its a BSD style license.

Comment: Ok, that license will only matter if you plan to re-distribute parts of python itself. Software written in the python language is normally not affected by the python license.

Answer (score 11):

BSD-3 clause is a very permissive license that does not require you disclosing your source code or the source code of the open source libraries. You are not required to allow your users to re-distribute the binaries either.

You are required to display any copyright statements from the BSD licensed libraries, and you are required to display the BSD license text somewhere as well. If your software is an application, this kind of information is usually shown in some kind of "About this software" dialog. The documentation is another place where it is commonly found.